# Access to outer method from jQuery 'closure'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use fnB in click handler. Is there any elegant solution? Thanks.

```
A = function() {
   ...
}

B = function() {
   ...
}
B.prototype = new A();
B.prototype.fnB = function() {}
B.prototype.fn = function() {
  // this isntanceof B -> true
  jQuery(selector).click(function() {
    this.fnB() // this instance of B -> false, this == $(selector) -> true
  }
}
```

---

Implementation based on SoWeLie's answer:

```
EventType = {
    ButtonClicked: 0
    ...
}

function Delegate(object, method) {
    return function() { method.apply(object, arguments); }
}

function Observable() {
    this._eventHandlers = {};
}

Observable.prototype = {
    addListener: function(eventType, listener) {
        if(!this._eventHandlers.eventType) {
            this._eventHandlers.eventType = [];
        }
        this._eventHandlers.eventType.push(listener);
    },

    removeListener: function(eventType, listener) {
        if(this._eventHandlers.eventType) {
            for(var i = this._eventHandlers.eventType.length; --i > -1;) {
                if(!listener || this._eventHandlers.eventType[i] == listener) {
                    this._eventHandlers.eventType.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    },

    fireEvent: function(eventType, data) {
        if(this._eventHandlers.eventType) {
            for(var i = 0; i < this._eventHandlers.eventType.length; ++i) {
                var handleEvent = this._eventHandlers.eventType[i];
                if(handleEvent) {
                    handleEvent(this, data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Dialog.Buttons = { ButtonOk: 0, ButtonCancel: 1, ButtonYes: 2, ButtonNo: 3, ButtonClose: 4 };
Dialog.prototype = new Observable();
Dialog.prototype.bindEvents = function() {
    $('#dlgButtonOk', this._$el).click(Delegate(this, function() {
        this.fireEvent(EventType.ButtonClicked, Dialog.Buttons.ButtonOk );
    }));
    $('#dlgButtonCancel', this._$el).click(this, function() {
        this.fireEvent(EventType.ButtonClicked, Dialog.Buttons.ButtonCancel );
    });

$(function() {
    dialog = new Dialog('.dialogWnd')
    dialog.addListener(EventType.ButtonClicked, function() {alert(1)})
});
```

????
Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.
???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant solution is to use the apply method of a function:

```
var hitch = function (scope, callback) {
        return function () {
            return callback.apply(scope, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        }
    }
```

Change your code like so:

```
jQuery(selector).click(hitch(this, function() {
    this.fnB() // this instance of B -> false, this == $(selector) -> true
  }))
```

Notice the call to hitch on your anonymous function, this will ensure the cope is preserved within the click handler.

Comment: I've found a solutions, basically the same like your based on delegates (used in C#): http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/04/javascripts-slippery-this-reference-and-other-monsters-in-the-closet.aspx. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
var that = this;
jQuery(selector).click(function() {
  that.fnB()
}
```

Or you could use `bind`, but it's not widely supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a closure:

```
B.prototype.fn = function() {
    // this isntanceof B -> true
    var that = this;
    jQuery(selector).click(function() {
        that.fnB();
    });
};
```

Comment: I don't like it but it's probably the only possible solution in JS. Thanks.